# query post from custom post type and display upto two categories on current post

Tags: wordpress

I want to make a query for post added with a different Post Type:

The original query was like this:

```
 query_posts( "post_type=market-item&posts_per_page=".$post_per_page."&paged=".$paged );
```

I don't know where or how to specify the logic that only show one category or two categories for custom post type

Here is part of the code:

```
<ul class="item-list list"> 
 <?php  
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;    
 $post_per_page=16;
//query_posts( "post_type=market-item&posts_per_page=".$post_per_page."&paged=".$paged    ); 
//query_posts('post_type=market-item',  );  

$args = array('post_type' => 'market-item','cat'=>13);

 query_posts($args );


 if(have_posts()) :while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 $image1= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sangvish_Image1', true );
 $image2= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sangvish_Image2', true );
  $terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'item-cat', '',        ' / ', '' ) );
 ?>      
 <li class="index-page-thumbnail">
 <div class="thumbnail">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
 <img src="<?php echo $image1; ?>"
 border="0"
alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"
title="<?php the_title(); ?>"
height="80"
width="80"
class="thumbnail-image-popup preload no_preview"
image-preview-width=""
image-preview-height=""
data-item-name="<?php the_title(); ?>"
data-item-author="<?php the_author(); ?>"
data-item-category="<?php echo $terms_as_text; ?>"
 data-item-cost="<sup><?php echo sangvish_currency_simb(); ?></sup><?php echo     get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sangvish_price', true ); ?>"
 popup-large="<?php echo $image2; ?>" />
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$cnt = 1;           
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' | ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if($cnt<=2) {
            $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
        }
       $cnt++;
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
```